# Compiler C2491 error: solution requires loss of data?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

Using VS2017, I made a project from the auto-generated `.cpp`/`.h` files generated by this line (I am adding this to illustrate how I reached this point):

```
protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --cpp_out=dllexport_decl=MY_EXPORT_MACRO:$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR\gameinformation.proto
```

This line generated the files correctly and with no errors or warnings, my question does not refer to the generation of the files, rather their compilation to a `.dll`. I am specifically looking for a way to fix the error I encountered afterwards.

I have defined the macro as so in the `.h` file (I am adding this in case it is linked to the error I am dealing with):

```
#if BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION
#define MY_EXPORT_MACRO __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#pragma comment( 'lib', "gameinformation.lib" )
#define MY_EXPORT_MACRO __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

Now, a portion of the generated code (`.cpp`) is as follows:

```
const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets[] PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE( protodesc_cold ) = {
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, _has_bits_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, _internal_metadata_ ),
    ~0u, // no _extensions_
    ~0u, // no _oneof_case_
    ~0u, // no _weak_field_map_
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, gamemessage_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, eacmessagebuffer_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, eacmessagelength_ ),
    0,
    1,
    2,
};
```

This is the only definition/assignment of a value to this variable in the whole project.

When I try to compile my project, this portion of code throws this error:

```
Error   C2491   'TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

This is the error I am trying to resolve, specifically.

I googled this, and according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/c2491-define-data-member-dllimport), I need to get rid of the value assignment, ie, only retain this much:

```
const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets[] PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE( protodesc_cold )
```

This does not seem like a robust solution to me. This file was automatically generated and I am quite sure those values are important.

If I have to take the Microsoft solution, does it matter if these values are lost? Is there somewhere else I can put them?
Or is there an alternative?

Comment: `dll_import` means the referenced data is defined elsewhere, so you can (re)declare it but you cannot define it *again*, which is what C2491 says. Don't know what `protoc` is but it's either wrong in this case or you need to use it with some other/additional options.

Comment: I have trawled the code but this is the only definition of that variable

Comment: Going by the macro you quote, it's probably defined in `gameinformation.lib`.

Comment: @dxiv `gameinformation.lib` doesn't seem to exist... Was I supposed to define that first? I thought it would be generated once I successfully compiled this project

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what you are actually building. If you build the `.lib` then you should define `BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION`. If you do not define it, that means you want to *use* the `.lib`, instead.

Comment: @dxiv Oh that could be what I'm doing wrong. I was under the impression that the `.lib` would be generated when I built my project.
Now I need to work out hiw to make that.. .thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @dxiv I double checked and that line is auto-generated too... So now I'm just extra confused