# Error C2491 definition of dllimport static data member not allowed - how to fix without loss of information?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I used a 3rd party script to automatically generate a C++ project. Specifically a `.cpp` and `.h` file that I now wish to compile to a `.dll` with VS2017.

A portion of the generated code (`.cpp`) is as follows:

```
const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets[] PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE( protodesc_cold ) = {
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, _has_bits_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, _internal_metadata_ ),
    ~0u, // no _extensions_
    ~0u, // no _oneof_case_
    ~0u, // no _weak_field_map_
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, gamemessage_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, eacmessagebuffer_ ),
    PROTOBUF_FIELD_OFFSET(::GameInfo::GameInformation, eacmessagelength_ ),
    0,
    1,
    2,
};
```

This is the only definition/assignment of a value to this variable in the whole project.

When I try to compile my project (Release x64 in VS), this portion of code throws this error:

```
Error   C2491   'TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets': definition of dllimport static data member not allowed
```

This is the error I am trying to resolve, specifically.

I googled this, and according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/c2491-define-data-member-dllimport), I need to get rid of the value assignment, ie, only retain this much:

```
const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::uint32 TableStruct_gameinformation_2eproto::offsets[] PROTOBUF_SECTION_VARIABLE( protodesc_cold )
```

This does not seem like a robust solution to me. This file was automatically generated and I am quite sure those values are important.

After reading [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401359/c2491-stdnumpunct-elemid-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member-n), I ca nconfirm that this code (`.h`) contains a `define` that switches between `dllimport` and `dllexport` (so please don't mark as duplicate):

```
#if BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION
#define MY_EXPORT_MACRO __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define MY_EXPORT_MACRO __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

If I have to take the Microsoft solution, does it matter if these values are lost? Is there somewhere else I can put them?
Or is there an alternative?

Comment: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7567

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the link! I took a look at it, and compared their patch with what I already had in `google/protobuf/parse_context.h` but I do not have the elements they removed. I did add the elements they added, but they were only comments, and this does not seem to have improved my situation

Comment: I'm sorry that there is no other method besides Microsoft's method, and it is impossible to determine whether those values are important. Static data members cannot specify a definition in the same program in which a dllimport class is defined. Besides, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491990/c-definition-of-dllimport-static-data-member) may help you.

Comment: @BarrnetChou Thanks for the answer, I did delete the definition of this variable and it cleared the error for that one; I had the identical problem with another variable (that is `const`), so I did the same. However, that one now throws this error `'const' object must be initialized if not 'extern'` as well as `definition of dllimport static data member not allowed`. Any idea as to what I can do about that?

Comment: @JessicaChambers This is [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64503877/compiler-c2491-error-solution-requires-loss-of-data) you asked a couple of days ago, and my same comment stands. The way the `.h` is written implies that if you build the .lib then you have to define `BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION` in the makefile or the `cl` command line, otherwise you are supposed to just use the definition provided elsewhere in the library, so you cannot change or (re)initialize that.

Comment: @dxiv I'm not using the .lib -that line was just a poor copy/paste that doesn't seem to be necessary to the project. I'm trying to compile it with VS (not the cmd line), do you know where I would define `BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION` in this case?

Comment: @JessicaChambers The error indicates that there is a `__declspec(dllimport)` somewhere in the code that you don't show, but it's hard to guess why or where without the full context.

Comment: The only occurrence of the phrase `__declspec(dllimport)` is the one shown here in `BUILD_GAMEINFORMATION`

Comment: It seems difficult to judge the cause based on these information.

Comment: @BarrnetChou I can provide any other information you require, these elements just seemed the most relevant to me